# Qt TCP sockets working on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sockets, tcp

I am using QTcpSocket to send data between a client and a server.

The server works perfectly fine on Linux, yet on Windows it will only receive one message and not more after that. `readyRead()` is just never emitted again.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Some of the code which I deemed to be important for this question:

server sending:

```
void Server::sendData(Client *client, QString data)
{
    if (client->socketDescriptor == socketDescriptor) {
        data = data + CRLF;

//      Have also tried to use socket->flush(), same problem.
        socket->write(data.toUtf8());
        socket->waitForBytesWritten();
    }
}
```

server receiving:

```
// this slot is connected to the readyRead() signal
void Server::readData()
{
    // on Windows this is called exactly once for each client
    // every additional messages just don't seem to arrive at the server
    QString msg = QString(socket->readAll());
    emit receivedData(this, &msg);
}
```

I just don't get why it works on Linux, yet not on windows...

Comment: But maybe client does not respond anymore? What happens on the client side?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on the server and not the client? Can you confirm the client is sending data? Use a tool like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org) to confirm proper data transmission.

Comment: thank you, I have figured it out finally. The problem was that my socket was not in the same thread as the object containing it. A simple `socket->moveToThread(this->thread())` solved the issue. However, I'm not quite sure why... (I'm not very experienced with Qt)